# First principles calculations beyond s-wave BCS superconductors

Tags: ab-initio-calculations, condensed-matter, superconductivity, bcs-theory

Conventional superconductors are often modelled using Bardeen-Cooper-Schrieffer (BCS) theory with an s-wave order parameter, but not all superconductors describable with BCS theory have an s-wave order parameter.

Are there any particular requirements needed to model p- or d-wave BCS superconductors in *ab initio* calculations, which are not included when modelling s-wave superconductors?

Comment: Could you provide an example of a conventional superconductor without an s-wave order parameter? Because, in the literature I'm familiar with, the conventional superconductors are always associated with s-wave Cooper pairing.

Comment: @Anyon I am thinking of superconductors that can be explained with BCS theory, but have a p- or d-wave order parameter. From a quick search, I do seem to find that there are more articles that take "conventional superconductor" to imply an s-wave order parameter, rather than meaning just describable with BCS theory (regardless of whether there is an s-, p- or d-wave order parameter). I will edit my question for clarity.